# How to use user uploaded xlsx on shiny app which would use that data to generate choices for filter input?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that takes a dataframe from which some filter options are generated so that users can pick one, and a table is generated as the output. That dataframe originates from an .xlsx file which is read at the beginig of the app. But i would like the user to upload the file.
The data has the following structure:

```
ID    <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)
Provincia <- c("Santa Fe",  "Santa Fe", "Cordoba"   ,"Santa Fe" ,"Santa Fe",    "Cordoba",  "Cordoba"   ,"Santa Fe",    "Cordoba"   ,"Cordoba"  ,"Santa Fe",    "Santa Fe", "Santa Fe"  ,"Santa Fe",    "Santa Fe", "Cordoba",  "Cordoba"   ,"Cordoba","Santa Fe")
Ciudad <- c("Carlos Paz",   "Esperanza" ,"Rafaela"  ,"Carlos Paz",  "Carlos Paz"    ,"Rafaela"  ,"Villa General" ,"Belgrano"    ,"Villa General Belgrano",  "Rafaela","Esperanza",  "Rafaela",  "Esperanza" ,"Esperanza",   "Villa General" ,"Belgrano",    "Carlos Paz",   "Carlos Paz",   "Esperanza")
Valor1 <- rpois(n = 19, lambda = 10) 
Valor2 <- runif(n = 19, min = 1, max = 10)
Color <- c("Rojo",  "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul","Rojo",  "Azul","Rojo",  "Azul","Rojo",  "Azul","Rojo",  "Azul","Rojo",  "Azul","Rojo",  "Azul","Rojo",  "Azul","Rojo")
df <- data.frame(ID,Provincia,Ciudad,Valor1,Valor2,Color)
```

This is the working shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(arsenal)

base <- read_excel("Libro1.xlsx")

prov_list <- base %>% distinct(Provincia)%>%arrange(Provincia)
todos <- " ALL"
prov_list <- rbind(todos, prov_list)
prov_list <- split(prov_list,prov_list$Provincia)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Título"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "var1",
        label = "Select province",
        choices = ls(prov_list),
        selected = " ALL",
        multiple = FALSE
      ),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "var2",
        label = "Select city",
        choices = NULL
      )
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel(
          "Tabla 1",
          htmlOutput("table")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$var1,{
    updateSelectInput(session,'var2',
                      choices=c(" ALL",unique(base$Ciudad[base$Provincia==input$var1])))
  })
  
  My_Uploaded_Data <- reactive({
    My_Uploaded_Data<-base
    My_Uploaded_Data
  })
  
  filtered_data_0 <- reactive({
    filtered_data_0<-My_Uploaded_Data()
    filtered_data_0 %>%filter(if(input$var1!= ' ALL')  (Provincia == input$var1) else TRUE)
  })
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    filtered_data<-filtered_data_0()
    filtered_data %>%filter(if(input$var2!= ' ALL')  (Ciudad == input$var2) else TRUE)
  })
  
  
  controles <- reactive({
    tableby.control(
      test = T,
      total = T,
      numeric.test = "anova", cat.test = "chisq",
      numeric.stats = c("meanCI"),
      cat.stats = c("countpct"),
      stats.labels = list(
        meanCI = "Media (95%CI)",
        countpct = "n (%)")
    )
  })
  
  output$table <- function(){
    
    x <- filtered_data()
    
    my_controls <- controles()
    
    tab1 <- tableby(Color ~ Valor1+Valor2,
                    data=x,
                    control=my_controls)
    
    aver <- as.data.frame(summary(tab1,digits=1,
                                  text = "html"))
    
    kable(aver,align = "lccc", escape = FALSE)%>%
      kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover","condensed","responsive"), full_width = TRUE)
    
  }
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And here i tried to get the user to upload the file:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(arsenal)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Título"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("upload", "Please select file", accept = c(".xlsx")),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "var1",
        label = "Select province",
        choices = ls(prov_list),
        selected = " ALL",
        multiple = FALSE
      ),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "var2",
        label = "Select city",
        choices = NULL
      )
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel(
          "Tabla 1",
          htmlOutput("table")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  base <- reactive({
    upload <- input$upload
    base <- read_excel(upload$datapath)
  })
  
  prov_list <- base() %>% distinct(Provincia)%>%arrange(Provincia)
  todos <- " ALL"
  prov_list <- rbind(todos, prov_list)
  prov_list <- split(prov_list,prov_list$Provincia)
  
  
  observeEvent(input$var1,{
    updateSelectInput(session,'var2',
                      choices=c(" ALL",unique(base()$Ciudad[base()$Provincia==input$var1])))
  })
  
  My_Uploaded_Data <- reactive({
    My_Uploaded_Data<-base()
    My_Uploaded_Data
  })
  
  filtered_data_0 <- reactive({
    filtered_data_0<-My_Uploaded_Data()
    filtered_data_0 %>%filter(if(input$var1!= ' ALL')  (Provincia == input$var1) else TRUE)
  })
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    filtered_data<-filtered_data_0()
    filtered_data %>%filter(if(input$var2!= ' ALL')  (Ciudad == input$var2) else TRUE)
  })
  
  
  controles <- reactive({
    tableby.control(
      test = T,
      total = T,
      numeric.test = "anova", cat.test = "chisq",
      numeric.stats = c("meanCI"),
      cat.stats = c("countpct"),
      stats.labels = list(
        meanCI = "Media (95%CI)",
        countpct = "n (%)")
    )
  })
  
  output$table <- function(){
    
    x <- filtered_data()
    
    my_controls <- controles()
    
    tab1 <- tableby(Color ~ Valor1+Valor2,
                    data=x,
                    control=my_controls)
    
    aver <- as.data.frame(summary(tab1,digits=1,
                                  #labelTranslations = my_labels,
                                  text = "html"))
    
    kable(aver,align = "lccc", escape = FALSE)%>%
      kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover","condensed","responsive"), full_width = TRUE)
    
  }
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But i get the error : 'Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer', which i'm not sure how to go about fixing. Any help would be much apreciated!

Comment: For one, it looks like you are trying to use base() outside of a reactive context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the issue mentioned in the comment by @stomper uploading the data from an xlsx file requires some more work, e.g. you have to take care that  the `reactive`s are only triggered after the `choices` are set. Otherwise you will get a bunch of errors popping up. This could for example achieved using `req`. Also, I added an `observeEvent` to update the choices for the first `selectInput` as these are only known after the xlsx file is uploaded. Finally I simplified your code a bit.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(arsenal)
library(kableExtra)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Título"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("upload", "Please select file", accept = c(".xlsx")),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "var1",
        label = "Select province",
        choices = NULL,
        selected = " ALL",
        multiple = FALSE
      ),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "var2",
        label = "Select city",
        choices = NULL
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel(
          "Tabla 1",
          htmlOutput("table")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  base <- reactive({
    req(input$upload)

    upload <- input$upload

    read_excel(upload$datapath)
  })

  prov_list <- reactive({
    req(base())
    prov_list <- unique(base()$Provincia)
    c(" ALL", prov_list)
  })

  observeEvent(prov_list(), {
    updateSelectInput(session, "var1", choices = prov_list())
  })

  observeEvent(input$var1, {
    choices <- base()$Ciudad
    if (input$var1 != " ALL") choices <- choices[base()$Provincia == input$var1]
    choices <- c(" ALL", unique(choices))
    
    updateSelectInput(session, "var2", choices = choices)
  })

  filtered_data <- reactive({
    req(base(), input$var1, input$var2)
    base() %>%
      {
        if (input$var1 != " ALL") filter(., Provincia == input$var1) else .
      } %>%
      {
        if (input$var2 != " ALL") filter(., Ciudad == input$var2) else .
      }
  })

  controles <- reactive({
    tableby.control(
      test = T,
      total = T,
      numeric.test = "anova", cat.test = "chisq",
      numeric.stats = c("meanCI"),
      cat.stats = c("countpct"),
      stats.labels = list(
        meanCI = "Media (95%CI)",
        countpct = "n (%)"
      )
    )
  })

  output$table <- function() {
    req(nrow(filtered_data()) > 0, controles())
    
    x <- filtered_data()

    my_controls <- controles()

    tab1 <- tableby(Color ~ Valor1 + Valor2,
      data = x,
      control = my_controls
    )

    aver <- as.data.frame(summary(tab1,
      digits = 1,
      text = "html"
    ))

    kable(aver, align = "lccc", escape = FALSE) %>%
      kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"), full_width = TRUE)
  }
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
Provincia <- c("Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Cordoba", "Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Cordoba", "Cordoba", "Santa Fe", "Cordoba", "Cordoba", "Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Santa Fe", "Cordoba", "Cordoba", "Cordoba", "Santa Fe")
Ciudad <- c("Carlos Paz", "Esperanza", "Rafaela", "Carlos Paz", "Carlos Paz", "Rafaela", "Villa General", "Belgrano", "Villa General Belgrano", "Rafaela", "Esperanza", "Rafaela", "Esperanza", "Esperanza", "Villa General", "Belgrano", "Carlos Paz", "Carlos Paz", "Esperanza")
Valor1 <- rpois(n = 19, lambda = 10)
Valor2 <- runif(n = 19, min = 1, max = 10)
Color <- c("Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo", "Azul", "Rojo")

df <- data.frame(ID, Provincia, Ciudad, Valor1, Valor2, Color)

writexl::write_xlsx(df, "temp.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So, I needed to wrap base on a `reactive` so that it could change with changed user input and be used later on the code, and also use `req` so that it would’t be triggered before the file was uploaded, if I understood correctly? Also thank you for simplifying the code, I will try to understand the changes and ask you if there is something I don’t understand, if you don’t mind!

Comment: More precisely: You have to make `prov_list` a `reactive`. Concerning the req. The issue is that when you start the app the machinery starts to work, i.e. shiny will create the "reactive graph" which means all reactives are called. In your "static" app this works fine as all ingredients are known. But in the "dynamic" case there is no dataset and no choices. And R will complain about that, e.g. you could try that by commenting out the req statements. The req tells shiny to run the code inside the reactive only when the needed ingredients are available.